In some case, is training from random weight initialization better than fine-tuning?
I just trained my deep learning model with a transformer for a 4-classes multi-classification problem. However, some batches only have 3 classes, making the model biased for those 3 classes and making the model not confident to infer the other class.
I fine-tuned with retraining, but this time I removed that domain specific case that some batch only has 3 classes, leaving the training set and validation containing only 4 classes, and setting with higher learning rate such as 0.1 compared to the base model of 0.001.
But why is my fine-tuned model not good? Its accuracy is about 60%-80% compared to base-model that has 90% accuracy.

A learning rate of 0.1 is generally quite high for fine-tuning, especially if you're working with a pre-trained model. Fine-tuning a model usually requires a smaller learning rate (like 0.0001 to 0.001 for your case) because you don't want to disrupt the pre-trained features too quickly. You might also try using a learning rate scheduler to gradually reduce the learning rate during training along with regularization techniques.
Also fine-tuning a model works well when the pre-trained model's learned features are already close to being useful for your problem. If the pre-trained model was trained on a dataset that has significantly different class distributions or domains such as including quite a few 3-class batches in your case, a fine-tuning process might not work as expected when you switch to a more balanced or different dataset. If the fine-tuning dataset is too different from the original domain-specific data, the model may "forget" the domain-specific features it learned in the base training phase. This is known as catastrophic forgetting. You might need a full retrain with the class balanced training data.
Finally your base model might have overfitted to the specific dataset it was trained on including the domain-specific cases. When you remove that data, the model might no longer generalize well to the new data distribution. In general the base model should be a good pretrained general-purpose foundational model, and then fine tune the model on your domain-specific dataset.
